How to train YOLOv8 with traingin data in S3 bucket?
It appears that model.train expects a path to a data.yml file, and that file needs to have a path to the training and validation sets. s3 references do not seem to be actual paths, I see people use data generators to use S3s for training. Does anyone have a tip on how to do that with YOLOv8?

The short answer is that one should not use S3 to access training data at the time of training. S3 is not designed for that, there are ways around it, like s3fs project, but this was not the designer's intent.
Among AWS services EFS or EBS are meant for this purpose, and with them things are straightforward - they provide a filesystem.
